# How can I set the tx ETH amount?

Tags: solidity, erc20

I know a user can send ETH to the contract/function manually, but is there way to request a specific amount directly in the code so that it is added to the gas fee, for example, the way dxsale.app does it when creating a presale (see screenshot below) - it adds the 0.1 ETH cost of presale to the 0.0072 gas fee for a total of 0.1072.

[image: Dxsale.app Presale cost is included in the transaction fee]

Can this be done in an ERC20 contract? I know I can receive ETH in a `payable` function, e.g.

```
    function deposit() payable public {
        require(msg.value > 0, "You need to send some Ether");
    }
```

but can I specify the amount I want to receive (for a flat fee), so that it is added to the tx cost?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TLDR: The contract function is executed **after** the transaction has been sent. So it's not possible to to set the transaction params from the contract.

---

> *is there way to request a specific amount directly in the code*

Not in the Solidity code. You can only throw an exception if the sent amount is not an expected value.

```
function deposit() payable public {
    require(msg.value == 0.1 ether, "You need to send 0.1 Ether");
}
```

You can specify the amount when you're creating the transaction request. For example MetaMask uses the [Ethereum Provider API](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/ethereum-provider.html#ethereum-request-args), so you can predefine the amount that MetaMask will show.

```
const params = [
  {
    from: '0xb60e8dd61c5d32be8058bb8eb970870f07233155',
    to: '0xd46e8dd67c5d32be8058bb8eb970870f07244567',
    value: '0x9184e72a', // 2441406250
  },
];

ethereum
  .request({
    method: 'eth_sendTransaction',
    params,
  });
```

But the user can override this option in their wallet, or they can always submit a transaction using a different way (not requested with the custom value).

---

The value (both in the `params` JS object and the Solidity `msg.value` global variable) always excludes the gas fees.

So if you're sending 0.1 ETH, the gas fees are added on top of that and the total cost might be 0.10012345. The `params.value` will contain 0.1 ETH (hex number in wei), as well as the `msg.value` will contain 0.1 ETH (decimal number in wei).

Comment: Thank you! So, if Metamask, in general, uses 10 as the gas fee (by default), there's no way to increase that just from the contract (even if the user can then change it)?

Comment: The contract execution happens **after** the transaction has been generated by MM and sent. So you're correct in the assumption - you can't specify the transaction params from  the contract.